# Polymer paper-icon-item inside iron-list: focus and toggle

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I just updated to the latest version of Polymer, and it seems like the behavior of `paper-icon-item` has changed. According to the source documentation for version 1.0.3, `paper-icon-item` now conforms to the `iron-control-state` and `iron-button-state` behaviors.

I have two issues: I'm now getting "focused" and "pressed" added to my elements whenever I interact with them in those ways. That's fine, however, an annoying focus border is being added to my elements, and I can't figure out how to style it away with CSS.

[image] [image]

At what point in the CSS stack can I access the focus border?

My other issue is that the elements (which are inside an `iron-list`) are now seemingly permanently in toggle mode, so clicking a selected item will deselect it, even though I haven't explicitly set the toggle behavior anywhere. According to the Polymer documentation, the `toggles` behavior *should* be set to `false` as the default.

Can anyone offer some insight to these behaviors? I need the cells to be non-toggling and with no focus border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :focus or :active CSS properties.
The demo for iron-list uses this:

```
.item:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #666;
}
```

If you are using a `paper-menu` you can use these mixins:

```
--paper-menu-selected-item
--paper-menu-focused-item
```

Read the documentation for more info.

Although you might find those annoying, try using your application without a mouse and only the keyboard. For accessibility you should probably not hide those.

Comment: Good point about accessibility. I'll still need to style the border to match the color scheme of my app, though. Thanks!

Comment: Any insight into the toggling behavior?

Comment: If you want to disable items so they are not clickable in the list use the `disabled` attribute. Not sure if this works with `iron-list`, but that's how the `iron-menu-behavior` demo works. You can use CSS to style disabled items however you want.
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-menu-behavior?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=Polymer.IronMenuBehavior

Comment: I want the items to be clickable and selectable, but I want them to stay selected when I click the same one again. for some reason, "select" is behaving like a "toggle," deselecting an item if it's already selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same issue in my project. Since I updated all the polymer elements, my custom elements won't show anymore.
I hope the polymer team is fixing this soon ...